# C++ thread delete itself at its end

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am writing a server with allow connection from multiple client in same time. I create a new thread for every new connection. The client communicate with the server with this thread. I need to unallocate the memory for the thread into the server process when the client disconnect from the server.

The problem is when I try to "delete the thread itself".

I write a little code to explain my problem. The Class C represent a new connection. I create a new object of this class dynamically for every connection. The function action is voluntarily simplified to explain the problem.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

mutex m;

class C {
  thread *t;

  static void action(int n, C* obj) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      m.lock();
      cout << "i:" << i << ", n:" << n << endl;
      m.unlock();
    }
    delete(obj);
  }

  public:
    C() : t(nullptr) {}

    ~C() {
      delete(t); // Work if I comment this line
    }

    void launch() {
      static int i = 0;
      t = new thread(action, i++, this);
    }

};

int main() {
  C *c1 = new C();
  c1->launch();

  this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(5));
  return 0;
}
```

Sorry for my English I am learning it.

Comment: Why are you even using pointers?  You can do this all with automatic objects which require no cleanup from you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This *is* C++ not C#, sigh.  olive: no need for `new` or pointers in the demonstrated code.  And avoid `using namespace std;`, `std` has too many symbols in it.

Comment: Consider using a thread _pool_ instead of creating a new thread for each new connection.  I don't know enough C++ to know if there's a good thread pool implementation that you can just use, but it's a simple idea:  You have a blocking queue of _tasks_ (In this case, each task is an object representing a client that's waiting to be served.), and you have some number of threads that loop forever trying to take tasks from the queue.  When a thread gets a task, it _performs_ the task (i.e., it serves the client), and then instead of dying, it goes back to wait for the next task.

Comment: How about a `std::async` which uses a promise/future approach to store the results when a thread ends?

Answer (score 3):

**Before you destroy a `std::thread`, you must "join" it with `t->join()`.**

Refer to [this documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread):

> If `*this` has an associated thread (`joinable() == true`), `std::terminate()` is called.

More fatally, though, you're trying to do all this from within the thread itself. You can't do that:

> **Exceptions**
>   `std::system_error` if an error occurs.
>
> **Error Conditions**
>   `resource_deadlock_would_occur` if `this->get_id() == std::this_thread::get_id()` (deadlock detected)

By the way, you should lose that dynamic allocation. You don't need it.

Comment: If I try to join the thread just before delete it the program throw an exception "std::system_error"

Comment: @olive007: Took a closer look at `action`. Looks like you're trying to delete the thread... from itself. Why? You're hitting the `resource_deadlock_would_occur` error condition. I think you should revisit your design!

Comment: Year I am trying to do that. I delete the thread from itself because if I don't do it that a memory leak and my server use too memory.

Comment: @olive007: Of course you don't want to leak memory, but you also shouldn't have memory cleaning itself. Your main thread should be managing its worker threads, including their cleanup.

Comment: I change my design. Now I cleanup the memory into the main tread. Here a example : https://gist.github.com/olive007/b4abead4c23a87bacb659aee1e4996b9

Comment: @olive007: Better! You still have unnecessary dynamic allocation, and you could do away with some of those mutexes (using atomics instead), but that's good

Answer (score 1):

Calling a destructor on a thread that is `joinable` is specified as a termination of a program. It must be either `joined` or `detached`.

Also you should be using those RAII helpers, and lock_guards for mutexes as if exception occurs you won't properly release locks etc.

As a side-note: using one thread per connection isn't the best use of the resources, unless you expect to have a small number of simultaneous connections.

Answer (score 1):

Use std::thread::detach.

> Separates the thread of execution from the thread object, allowing execution to continue independently. Any allocated resources will be
> freed once the thread exits.
>
> After calling detach ****this*** no longer owns
> any thread.

Description copied from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach
which has an example.

So do not delete *t* in action.
Instead call detach after creating the thread:

```
void launch() {
  static int i = 0;
  t = new thread(action, i++, this);
  t->detach();
  delete t;
  // because t is detached before the delete 
  // the thread will keep running till it ends 
  // then resources are freed
}
```

Though no need for the heap here so it is neater to not use new.
Also no need to remember the thread object.
After calling detach it has no use.

```
void launch() {
  static int i = 0;
  std::thread tmp_thread(action, i++, this);
  tmp_thread.detach();
}
```

Note the second argument to action (third argument to thread constructor) is of course meaningless now.